# How Do I Get 2 Columns with Different Where Conditions in 1 SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query to calculate Month to Date quantity of inventory sold. It works fine:

```
SELECT customer.customer_name as 'Customer', item_id as 'Item ID', item_desc                                                     
AS 'Description', unit_price AS 'Cost', COALESCE(sum(qty_shipped), 0) as 'MTD Sales'
FROM p21_sales_history_report_view           
JOIN customer on customer.customer_id = p21_sales_history_report_view.corp_address_id
WHERE invoice_date between CAST('2017-03-01' as date) and CAST('2017-03-31' as date)
GROUP BY customer.customer_name, item_desc, item_id,  unit_price
ORDER BY customer.customer_name, item_desc
```

However, I also want a second column named 'YTD Sales' (with a WHERE condition of 2017-01-01 to 2017-03-31) next to the MTD column.  How would I get both in 1 query?  I tried something like this but it didn't work, it just gave me all 0 for MTD and YTD.  I'm sure I did something wrong:

```
SELECT customer.customer_name as 'Customer', item_id as 'Item ID', 
item_desc as 'Description', unit_price as 'Cost',  
COALESCE(sales_cost, 0) as 'Cost of Sales',  
SUM(CASE WHEN invoice_date BETWEEN CAST('2017-03-01' as date) and CAST('2017-03-31' as date) 
THEN COALESCE(qty_shipped,0) ELSE 0 END) as 'MTD Sales',
SUM(CASE WHEN invoice_date between CAST('2017-01-01' as date) and CAST('2017-03-31' as date) 
THEN COALESCE(qty_shipped,0) Else 0 END) as 'YTD Sales'
FROM p21_sales_history_report_view 
JOIN customer ON customer.customer_id = p21_sales_history_report_view.corp_address_id
GROUP BY item_desc, item_id, customer.customer_name, unit_price,
p21_sales_history_report_view.invoice_date, sales_cost
ORDER BY customer.customer_name, item_desc
```

Any suggestions? Obviously I can't use UNION because it will then give me all the rows twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks right - I would add a column SUM(COALESCE(qty_shipped,0)) to make sure you are indeed summing anything.  I am guessing something is wrong with your joins.

You can also do it by inner join on two sub queries

```
select * 
from 

( SELECT customer.customer_name as 'Customer', item_id as 'Item ID', item_desc                                                     
    AS 'Description', unit_price AS 'Cost', COALESCE(sum(qty_shipped), 0) as 'MTD Sales'
    FROM p21_sales_history_report_view           
    JOIN customer on customer.customer_id = p21_sales_history_report_view.corp_address_id
    WHERE invoice_date between CAST('2017-03-01' as date) and CAST('2017-03-31' as date)
    GROUP BY customer.customer_name, item_desc, item_id,  unit_price
    ORDER BY customer.customer_name, item_desc ) MTD
inner join 
( SELECT customer.customer_name as 'Customer', item_id as 'Item ID', item_desc                                                     
    AS 'Description', unit_price AS 'Cost', COALESCE(sum(qty_shipped), 0) as 'YTD Sales'
    FROM p21_sales_history_report_view           
    JOIN customer on customer.customer_id = p21_sales_history_report_view.corp_address_id
    WHERE invoice_date between CAST('2017-01-01' as date) and CAST('2017-03-31' as date)
    GROUP BY customer.customer_name, item_desc, item_id,  unit_price
    ORDER BY customer.customer_name, item_desc ) YTD
on MTD.Customer = YTD.Customer
and mtd.[Item ID] = YTD.[Item ID]
```

Comment: AMAZING.  Gave me what I needed.  Thank you so much.